# Wordpress WooCommerce Advanced Quantity Plugin issue

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a problem,maybe some of you can help me out fixing this.

Woocommerce updated to latest version and so is wordpress.

I have a woocommerce plugin that should let you chose product quantity with a dot between numbers,for example "1.2 / 3.4 / etc".

I belive it is not working due this Notice i get.[image: screenshot]

I have no errors in console.

Here is the code from those lines

```
Code for 1018,1020 line.
 *    Convert php array to javascript array
 *
 * @since 2.0.0
 */
private function convert_array_to_javascript_array($arr) {
    $j = 1;
    $arr_length = count($arr);
    if (!empty($arr)) {

        $javascript_arr = '';

        foreach ($arr AS $steps_interval) {
            for ($i = 0; $i <= 2; $i++) {
                if ($i == 2) {
                    $javascript_arr .= trim($steps_interval[$i]);
                } else {
                    $javascript_arr .= trim($steps_interval[$i] . ',');
                }
            }

            if($arr_length != $j) {
                $javascript_arr .= ',';
            }

            $j++;
        }

        return $javascript_arr;
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}
```

And the last code of the file.

```
/**
 * Generates interval array for our drop-down-input
 *
 * @since   2.0.0
 */
private function generate_select_intervals_input($product_id) {

    $intervals = $this->get_option($product_id, 'step-intervals');
    $select = array();
    $first = true;

    foreach($intervals AS $interval) {
        $step_minimum = $interval[0];
        $step_maximum = $interval[1];
        $step_interval_value = $interval[2];

        if(empty($step_minimum) || empty($step_maximum) || empty($step_interval_value)) {
            break;
        }

        for($i = $step_minimum; $i <= $step_maximum; $i += $step_interval_value) {


        if(strlen(round($i,2) - (int)round($i,2)) - 2 == 1) {
            $decimals = 1;
        } elseif(strlen(round($i,2) - (int)round($i,2)) - 2 < 1) {
            $decimals = 0;
        } else {
            $decimals = 2;
        }


            if($first) {
                $select[] = number_format($i, $decimals, '.', '');
                $first = false;
            } elseif($i != $step_minimum) {
                $select[] = number_format($i, $decimals, '.', '');
            }
        }
    }

    return $select;
}
```

}

Here is the php [file](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4ed78f0b7f5feff4ef59542eb3f76519).
Thank you.

Comment: please try print_r($arr) you are getting value in the array or not

Comment: Hi @AnandChoudhary , it prints this Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 0.1 ) )